# need to wrap text in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have given the css as shown .text { word-wrap : break-word; max-width: 100px} but still it's not working, the whole text is coming only in the single line

I am expecting the result that the big text to be get wrapped in next lines

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77620195/i-need-to-wrap-the-long-text-into-the-next-lines

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77620195/i-need-to-wrap-the-long-text-into-the-next-lines

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [CSS white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property.

Comment: Nope, I suggest you re-read the question (such as it is)